# Форма редактирования содержимого

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

На сайт нужно добавлять новости различного объема информации, включая картинки. Хотел спросить у Вас, как организовать форму добавления/редактирования? Слышал, что есть такая штука специальная (не знаю, как называется).
[image]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как эта штука называется, и как ею пользоваться с привязкой к БД.

Answer (score 2):

То, что изображено на картинке, это [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo). Подобных редакторов есть много. Визуальное редактирование они обеспечат, картинки, которые в статью захочется добавить, они позволяют выбрать с заранее указанного каталога на сервере или подгрузить в это каталог картинку и потом опять же выбрать. А вот как в базу сохранять и доставать оттудова - это уже задача скрипта.

Answer (score 2):

Эта штука называется **визуальный редактор**. Яркий пример сего чуда ["TinyMCE"](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Установить его - проще простого. Можешь прочитать [тут](http://www.simplecoding.org/tinymce-ustanovka-nastroyka-ispolzovanie.html)

А с БД связать тоже несложно, нужно просто вывести данные для редактирования в textarea, а потом из него обратно в базу.

Answer (score 2):

Это обычный **WYSIWYG**

Лучше всего использовать от [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Привязывается в обычному инпуту.

---

сразу ответов навалило.. удивительно, вопрос задан 2 часа назад, а ответы даны с разницей в 1 минуту.

Answer (score 2):

WYSIWYG - то вижу и получаю.

> и как ее пользоваться с привязкой к
> БД.

не совсем дошло до меня, что Вы имеете ввиду, по этому скажу как понял=)

```
<form action="get.php" type="post">
//WYSIWYG инструменты
<textarea name="text"></textarea>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

это был примерный код вашего редактора
главное поле в нём это `<textarea>` в котором то и рисуеться пишется и вставляеться что вам нужно и при отправки формы например в файл
**get.php** у вас там должен быть уже код который и сохранит в базу содержимое вошего редактора

Comment: Я имею ввиду то что текст будет храниться в поле текст, а картинки в отдельном каталоге. Вот как эту картинку выцепить оттуда и поместить в каталог и назад, или операция с картинками какая то другая олжна быть?

Comment: Если правильно настроить WYSIWYG редактор, то вам не надо думать о картинках, они сами сохраняться там где надо и будут выводиться в том тексте, что вы отредактировали в вашем редакторе и сохранили.

Если отформатировать текс в таком редакторе скажем, вставили картинку, то в БД он сохраниться как:

Какой нить текст <img src="IMG_URL"> Продолжение текста итд.

А на сайте он вместо кода <img> покажет картинку. А картинку редактор загрузит на сервер и сохранит.